# Write method about 15-5-3 division rule

Tags: algorithm

I have thoughts about a question asked to me in a job interview.

Problem is:

"Please write the function which satisfies the following conditions, when the user will enter the value. the value will be divided to 5 ", if the value will be divided to 15 the function will return only" the value will be divided to 15 ", if the value will be divided to the non 3 conditions system will return" the value will not be divided to 3/5/15 "

And I thought, I first checked that the number could be divided by 15. then to 5 and finally to 3. but I don't think it's that easy. When I look at the rule of divisibility by 15, I see that every number that is fully divisible by 3 and 5 can be divisible by 15.

In my opinion, I wrote this code:

```cs
if (a % 15 == 0) { Console.WriteLine("the value will be divided to 15"); }
            else if (a % 5 == 0) { Console.WriteLine("the value will be divided to 5"); }
            else if (a % 3 == 0) { Console.WriteLine("the value will be divided to 3"); }
            else { Console.WriteLine("the value will be divided to nothing"); }
```

I think it's a trick about the divisibility rule of 15, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You mean 'divided by', not 'divided to', I think? Also your questions isn't clear - are you asking if numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5 are also divisible by 15?

Comment: Looking at your code, if a number is divisible by 15 it is divisible by 5 and 3, so you don't need the second and third `if` checks.

Comment: @Sach the second and thirds `if`s are there when the number is *not* divisible by 15 (i.e 25 or 9).

Answer (score 2):

The rule works. We say that 15 divides a number `n` if there is an integer `q` such that

```
15q = n
```

We call `q` the *witness* to the fact that 15 divides `n`.

Since we can factor `15` into `3 * 5` or `5 * 3`, that's equivalent to saying

```
(3*5)q = n
(5*3)q = n
```

Becase integer multiplication is associative, that is the same as

```
3(5*q) = n
5(3*q) = n
```

As all three of 3, 5, and `q` are integers, this means `5*q` is the witness to the divisibility of `n` by 3, and `3*q` is the witness to the divisibility of `n` by 5.

Now, suppose that 15 does *not* divide `n`. That means there is no witness `q`. If 3 divides `n`, we know there is a `q` such that `3q = n`. We also know that 5 does not divide `q`, or else there would be some `p` such that `3*(5*p) = n`, and `p` would be the witness that 15 *does* divide `n`. A similar argument holds if 5 divides `n`. Thus, if you have already shown that 15 does not divide `n`, then at most *one* of 3 and 5 can also divide `n`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way to solve the problem: compute the [greatest common divisor (GCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of the number and 15. This reduces the number of divisions that need to be performed, and [reduces the amount of duplicated code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

The code would look like this:

```
int gcd = 1;
if (a % 3 == 0) { gcd *= 3; }
if (a % 5 == 0) { gcd *= 5; }

if (gcd != 1) { Console.WriteLine("the value will be divided to " + gcd); }
else { Console.WriteLine("the value will be divided to nothing"); }
```

This is also extensible to any number of prime factors by writing a proper GCD function.